# Displaying Same images in gridview Based on dropdown selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have Menu Table and product table and MenuId ins the common field
Example

Menu Table

```
MenuId MenuName 
11      Shirts    
12      Tshirts
```

Product Table

```
ProductId ProductName MenuId ProductImage
1          Levisshirts 11     image
2          white shirt 11     image2
```

have display image in girdview based on drop down selection but the problem is it display same image for every products my code as follows

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    if (!IsPostBack)
        ddlbind();
}
private void BindGridData()
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from rsa_ProductItemTable where  MenuId=" + Dropsearch.SelectedItem.Value, con);
    SqlDataAdapter daimages = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    daimages.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.Attributes.Add("bordercolor", "black");
}
public void ddlbind()
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from rsa_mastermenu", con);
    SqlDataAdapter daimages = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    daimages.Fill(dt);
    Dropsearch.DataSource = dt;
    Dropsearch.DataTextField = "MenuName";
    Dropsearch.DataValueField = "MenuId";
    Dropsearch.DataBind();
    Dropsearch.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "0"));
}
protected void Dropsearch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int imgid = int.Parse(Dropsearch.SelectedItem.Value);
    BindGridData();
}
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Image img = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("Image1");
        img.ImageUrl = "GridviewImage.ashx?ImID=" + Dropsearch.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong please help me with this

Comment: can you share your html code

Comment: i am unable to add html code

Comment: you can use <%# "path" + Eval("imageid")> in imageurl of aspx page

Comment: <ItemTemplate>    
     <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="300px"/>
     </ItemTemplate>

Comment: give your image path. i'll give you html markup

Comment: ImageUrl='<%# "GridviewImage.ashx?ImID=" + Eval("ProductID")%>'

Comment: tried That getting same output and i do have handler page too

Comment: Current code what you posted looks correct, look into `GridviewImage.ashx` code for any faults.

Answer (score 0):

Set image url in aspx ,
something like this

```
<ItemTemplate> 
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "your_path" + "ProductImage" %>'  
   Height="300px" Width="300px"/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Plese make sure your_path is physical path where image is stored, for example `"~/images/myimg"` and your image name is valid, for example `image.jpg` or `image1.png`

by this method you can show image in gridview.

Comment: IMage is Stored in Database

Comment: your database column is of image datatype ?

Comment: have you canvertde your image from bytes brfore showing it ?

Comment: yes it displaying the image but problem is first image for all products i mean it displays same image

Comment: then your code seem ok i think you should check your handler